# Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I use bellow command for restart apache:

```
# ./apachectl restart
```

But I get bellow error:

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 37 of /usr/local/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
>   Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.

my `httpd-vhosts.conf` is bellow:

```
[root@localhost bin]# vim /usr/local/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

 25     DocumentRoot "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs"
 26     ServerName 33.hk
 27     ServerAlias http://www.33.hk
 28     ErrorLog "logs/33.hk-error_log"
 29 </VirtualHost>
 30 
 31 <VirtualHost *:80>
 32     #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
 33     DocumentRoot "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/admin"
 34     ServerName 1.33.hk
 35     DirectoryIndex index.php
 36     <Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/admin">
 37       Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
 38       AllowOverride None
 39       Order allow,deny
 40       Allow from all
 41     </Directory>
 42     ErrorLog "logs/1.33.hk-error_log"
 43     CustomLog "logs/1.33.hk-access_log" common
 44 </VirtualHost>
```

My `37` line is `Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks`, can you tell me where is the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the docs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options :

> Normally, if multiple Options could apply to a directory, then the
>   most specific one is used and others are ignored; the options are not
>   merged. (See how sections are merged.) However if all the options on
>   the Options directive are preceded by a + or - symbol, the options are
>   merged. Any options preceded by a + are added to the options currently
>   in force, and any options preceded by a - are removed from the options
>   currently in force.

Simply mark the option with + to make clear you want to add it like this:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add prefix for both Indexes and FollowSymLinks.